# error related to returning a structure type from fucntion

Tags: c

I can not figure out why gcc thinks I am trying to assign an integer to a structure type. The following code is an attempt to combine functions from other shorter codes, which compiled and worked just fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
 struct date
 {
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
 };
struct time {
   int hour;
   int minutes;
   int seconds;
};
struct dateAndTime {
    struct date combinedDate;
    struct time combinedTime;
  };
void clockKeeper(struct dateAndTime dtAnTm )
  {
    //struct time testTime [] = { { 11, 59, 59 } , {12, 00, 00} , {1, 29, 59} , {23, 59, 59} , {19, 12, 27} };
    struct time testTime[] = {
      {.hour = 11, .minutes = 59, .seconds = 59},
      {.hour = 12, .minutes = 00, .seconds = 00},
      {.hour = 1,  .minutes = 29, .seconds = 59},
      {.hour = 23, .minutes = 59, .seconds = 59},
      {.hour = 19, .minutes = 12, .seconds = 27}
      };
    int i;
    struct time midNight = { 12, 00, 00};
    printf ("Here is what is in Midnight :%i:%i:%i \n", midNight.hour, midNight.minutes, midNight.seconds);
    for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      {

         printf("Time is:  %.2i:%.2i:%.2i\n", testTime[i].hour, testTime[i].minutes, testTime[i].seconds);
         testTime[i] = timeUpdate (testTime[i]);
         printf("....one second later%.2i:%.2i:%.2i\n", testTime[i].hour, testTime[i].minutes, testTime[i].seconds);
         //if (testTime[i].hour > midNight.hour)
          // testTime[i]= dateUpdate (testTime[i]);
      }
  }
struct time timeUpdate ( struct time now)
  {
    ++now.seconds;
    if ( now.seconds == 60 ) { // next minute
         now.seconds = 0;
        ++now.minutes;
         if ( now.minutes == 60 ) {
         now.minutes = 0;
         now.hour++;
         if ( now.hour == 24 )  // midnight
         now.hour = 0;
         }
      }
  return now;
  }
struct date dateUpdate (struct date today)
{
   struct date tomorrow;
   int numberOfDays (struct date d);

   if (today.day != numberOfDays (today) ) {
      tomorrow.day = today.day + 1;
      tomorrow.month = today.month;
      tomorrow.year = today.year;
}
else if (today.month == 12 ) {
     tomorrow.day = 1;
     tomorrow.month = 1;
     tomorrow.year = today.year + 1;
}
else {
     tomorrow.day = 1;
     tomorrow.month = today.month + 1;
     tomorrow.year = today.year;
}
return tomorrow;
}
int numberOfDays (struct date d)
{
int days;
bool isLeapYear (struct date d);
const int daysPerMonth[12] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
if ( isLeapYear (d) == true && d.month == 2 )
   days = 29;
else
   days = daysPerMonth[d.month - 1];
return days;
}
// Function to determine if it's a leap year
bool isLeapYear (struct date d)
{
bool leapYearFlag;
if (( d.year % 4 == 0 && d.year % 100 !=0) || d.year % 400 == 0 )
    leapYearFlag = true;   // It's a leap year
else leapYearFlag = false; // Not a leap year
return leapYearFlag;
}
int main (void)
  {
void clockKeeper(struct dateAndTime dtAnTm);
bool isLeapYear (struct date d);
int numberOfDays (struct date d);
struct time timeUpdate(struct time now);
struct date dateUpdate (struct date today);
return 0;
  }
```

I get the following error:

```
 gcc  .c -o 
.c: In function 'clockKeeper':
.c:28:22: error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct time' from type 'int'
          testTime[i] = timeUpdate (testTime[i]);
                      ^
.c:31:23: error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct time' from type 'int'
            testTime[i]= dateUpdate (testTime[i]);
                   ^
.c: At top level:
.c:34:13: error: conflicting types for 'timeUpdate'
 struct time timeUpdate ( struct time now)
             ^
.c:28:24: note: previous implicit declaration of 'timeUpdate' was here
          testTime[i] = timeUpdate (testTime[i]);
                        ^
.c:49:13: error: conflicting types for 'dateUpdate'
 struct date dateUpdate (struct date today)
             ^
.c:31:25: note: previous implicit declaration of 'dateUpdate' was here
            testTime[i]= dateUpdate (testTime[i]);
                         ^
make: *** [] Error 1
```

I have updated the array of structures testTime[] and commented out the dateUpdate () call as I am convinced is incorrect. I still see the errors regarding type mismatch:

```
.c:28:22: error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct time' from type 'int'
          testTime[i] = timeUpdate (testTime[i]);
                      ^
```

Comment: You don't have a prototype for `timeUpdate()` visible to `clockKeeper()`. Recommend turning on warnings for implicit function declaration.

Comment: Some hints: 1. name your source file something better than just `.c`, e.g. `mydatesource.c`. 2. compile it with all warnings & debug info into a meaningful executable name (e.g. `mydateprog`), e.g. `gcc -Wall -g mydatesource.c -o mydateprog`. 3. Improve the source code till you get no warnings. 4. Learn to use the `gdb` debugger & [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Spend days reading a good C programming book, and some good [C reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of problems in clockKeeper:

1. one right way to initialize `struct time testTime[]` is this:

   ```
   struct time testTime[] = {
         {.hour = 11, .minutes = 59, .seconds = 59},
         {.hour = 12, .minutes = 00, .seconds = 00},
         {.hour = 1,  .minutes = 29, .seconds = 59},
         {.hour = 23, .minutes = 59, .seconds = 59},
         {.hour = 19, .minutes = 12, .seconds = 27}
   };
   ```
2. the call `dateUpdate(timeTime[i])` has a type mismatch. Your logic is incorrect here.

Comment: Got it. But I still see errors regarding trying to assign int to sturct type.

Comment: @Bonan- I tried the struct you created also. Same result.

Comment: move timeUpdate above clockKeeper

Comment: Same as before: c:35:22: error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct time' from type 'int'
          testTime[i] = timeUpdate (testTime[i]); c:41:13: error: conflicting types for 'timeUpdate'
 struct time timeUpdate ( struct time now)
             ^c:35:24: note: previous implicit declaration of 'timeUpdate' was here
          testTime[i] = timeUpdate (testTime[i]);
                        ^
                      ^ I updated the body of the post with the latest changes.

Comment: You d man! I moved the function prototypes, but did not know the specifications depend on each other also. It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct time testTime [] = { 11, 59, 59, 12, 00, 00, 1, 29, 59, 23, 59, 59, 19, 12, 27 };
```

is incorrect since the RHS is an array of `int`s. You can use:

```
// Using multiple lines makes the code readable
struct time testTime [] = { {11, 59, 59},
                            {12, 00, 00},
                            {1, 29, 59},
                            {23, 59, 59},
                            {19, 12, 27} };
```

Comment: I noticed that in order for my original implementation to work, I would have to (type cast). Regardless, the original method pointed out by RS is more clear.

Comment: @maverick, I don't know why you need to cast. I don't seem to have a problem with the code I have in my answer. See http://ideone.com/45Z5nq.